# Different radical for the same Kanji

Tags: kanji, radicals

[image]

Sometimes in social media, and especially in videogames, I found this kanji above (with the keyboard I can't type it, and copy and paste doesn't work either) with the same exact meaning of 終わる.

Same thing occurs with the kanji for 続ける, where the left radical is different. Another instance is the verb 直る, which is slightly different.

Why is that?

Comment: 直 rendered in a Chinese font doesn't have the left vertical bar and the other two vertical bars touch the horizontal bar at the bottom.